# Accessing a freed pointer, shouldn't output be a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers

```
Example -
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void alloco(int **ppa)
{
    int i;
    int *p;
    printf("inside alloco");
    p = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    memset(p,0x0, 10 * sizeof(int));
    p[4] = 9;
    p[9] = 9;
    p[8] = 123; // fill the 10 chunks of memory
    printf("size of a %d \n", sizeof(p));
    free(p); //free the pointer!!
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("a[%d] = %d \n", i, p[i]); //accessing a freed pointer, shouldn't it crash?!
    *ppa = p; // pointing to a freed address.
}

int main()
{
    int *app = NULL;  
    int i;
    printf("inside main\n");
    alloco(&app);
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      printf("app[%d] = %d \n", i, app[i]); //getting the same filled contents!
    return 0;
}
```

Accessing a freed pointer that is pointer *p* inside alloco, shouldn't the output produce a expected segmentation fault? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Accessing a freed pointer is an undefined behavior. The program may or may not crash. For dynamically allocated memory, you should check if the pointer is still valid, before accessing its contents.

Comment: @askmish since you said check if the pointer is still valid, how do i do that? if you mean checking it against NULL, i printed the pointing address before and after the free, they both point to same location.

Comment: There is no way to check if a (non-null) pointer is valid in standard C. Some libraries might offer such features, but I don't know of one.

Comment: By valid I meant checking if the pointer is NOT NULL. `free` should set the pointer to NULL. And as Mat pointed out, indeed there's no way for checking if the pointer is a dangling one or not and other such invalid pointer states in standard C and you could still end up in another UB even after the NULL check.

Comment: @askmish -  "free should set the pointer to NULL" - but it doesn't. I somewhat suspect you meant *you* (the caller) should set the pointer to NULL after invoking `free`.

Comment: @Coder you have to explicity set the pointer to NULL after calling free. free  only free that memory i.e. it can be used for other purpose. It doesn't do any resetting its memory content to 0 nor its set pointer to NULL.

Comment: @ WhozCraig Yes, I meant after `free` one should set the pointer to NULL. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: free() makes no change what so ever to the passed in parameter (and the parameter would have to always be ** for free() to change the contents of the parameter variable.   It is, however, very good programming practice to set the parameter variable to NULL after the call to free().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code has *undefined behavior* because you're accessing memory that you do not own anymore (since you freed it).

Undefined behavior means that anything can happen. Anything at all, including your program behaving as if you hadn't freed, segfaulting, printing random garbage.

You cannot reason about the behavior of a program that is undefined. You cannot rely on it doing anything specific like triggering a segmentation fault.

---

Some standardeese to back up the claims above, from a C11 draft:

> #### §6.2.4 Storage duration of objects
>
> 2. The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists, has a constant address, and retains its last-stored value throughout its lifetime. **If an object is referred to outside of its
>    lifetime, the behavior is undefined.** The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

> #### §7.22.3 Memory management functions
>
> [...] The lifetime of an allocated object extends from the allocation
> **until the deallocation**. [...]

And the famous *Undefined behavior* definition:

> #### 3.4.3 undefined behavior
>
> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard **imposes no requirements**
>
> <sub>NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined behaviour.

You have allocated only `10 * sizeof(int)` bytes, for which the malloc-implementation likely does not request  separate memory pages from the kernel. So after the `free` the memory is not returned to the OS and is therefore still accessible by the process. That is, no segmentation fault occurs.

If you would allocate `1000000  * sizeof(int)` bytes, the memory would likely be allocated in separate pages and would be returned to the OS by the `free` and you would get the segmentation fault you have expected.

If you compile the program with `-fsanitize=address` (at least gcc version 4.8.0 required) and run it you get an error report by AddressSanitizer:  heap-use-after-free.